# Displaying 6.5235375356299998e-07 without exponential notation

Tags: python, floating-point, exponential

I have to convert exponential strings, like `6.5235375356299998e-07`,
to a float value, and display the result of my computation like 0.00000065235...
How can I do this in a Python program?

Comment: Did you try `float("6.5235375356299998e-07")`?

Comment: >>> a = 6.52353753563E-7
>>> float(a)
6.5235375356299998e-07

Comment: yes, i tried it, but the result is a exponent, too

Comment: @StefanS: What do you mean by "a float value" then?

Comment: I think he wants it *displayed*  as `0.00000065235375356299998`.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_notation for an explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`6.5235375356299998e-07` is a perfectly legal float even if there is an `e` in it. You can do the whole calculation with it:

```
>>> 6.5235375356299998e-07 * 10000000
6.5235375356300001

>>> 6.5235375356299998e-07 + 10000000
10000000.000000652
```

In the second case, many digits will disappear because of the precision of a python's float.

If you need the string representation without `e`, try this:

```
>>> '{0:.20f}'.format(6.5235375356299998e-07)
'0.00000065235375356300'
```

but it will become a string and you won't be able to do any calculus with it any more.

Comment: Super, that is a fine way! Thank you ver much.